UDP data from C program not Received to Java
Hello I have Program that wrote with C lang, In WireShark I see data from udp protocol From Source 192.168.23.150(which is my Server that Wrote in C lang) sended to Distanation 192.168.23.98(which is my PC) , Here the data from Capture :
2291071 1216.506108 192.168.23.150  192.168.23.98   UDP 60  27011 → 27011 Len=3

And the Value Data:02153f , the server loop send this in 500ms , As I correct this code can get udp data :
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class AdapterServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
                System.out.println("Interface name: " + networkInterface.getDisplayName());
                System.out.println("Interface name: " + networkInterface.getName());
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // Get the network interface by name (e.g., "eth0", "wlan0")
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName("ethernet_32773");

            // Get the InetAddress associated with the network interface
            InetAddress interfaceAddress = null;
            for (InterfaceAddress addr : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                if (addr.getAddress() instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    interfaceAddress = addr.getAddress();
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (interfaceAddress == null) {
                System.err.println("No IPv4 address found for the specified interface.");
                return;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Ipv4 is : " +interfaceAddress.getHostAddress() );
            }

            // Create a UDP socket bound to the interface address and port 27011
            socket = new DatagramSocket(27011, interfaceAddress);




                // Create a byte array to store incoming data
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

                // Create a DatagramPacket to receive data
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

                // Receive data
                socket.receive(receivePacket);

                // Extract received byte data
                byte[] receivedBytes = receivePacket.getData();

                // Print the received bytes in hexadecimal format
                System.out.print("Received bytes: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < receivePacket.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("%02X ", receivedBytes[i]);
                }
                System.out.println();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // Close the socket
                if (socket != null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }

    }
}

in this line   NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByName("ethernet_32773"); I get my interface that two devices link(I do it to know exactly is socket in java is in the same lan which is show me Ipv4 is : 192.168.23.98 and it is.)
So in my code I don't get any data from socket, but if I rewrite this in c I can get data! I check multiple example code in java and result is same. How can I get this data from udp port in java?

What is printed by your Java code?

nothing from receivePacket , Nothing!

Not really the right answer. I didn't ask you what is not printed. I asked you what is printed, which is why I put a specific emphasis in the question

just this line : Ipv4 is : 192.168.23.98 and all above this line :    System.out.println("Ipv4 is : " +interfaceAddress.getHostAddress() );

Not sure what your OS is, but when you double-check with netstat -n --udp --listen what is given?

Terminal 1: Ipv4 is : 192.168.2.206
Terminal 2: echo -e '\x02\x15\x3f' | socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:192.168.2.206:27011
Terminal 1: Received bytes: 02 15 3F 0A. Upshot: your code works. Is your C code sending that final newline char?

Why aren't you binding to 0.0.0.0 (or null in that constructor)?
